# TikZ: How to modify pie chart with individually adjustable colors and point number percentages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, charts, pie

### Example 1

I found [this](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart/) nice pie chart on the web as a template:

[image]

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
% Pie chart
% Author: Robert Vollmert
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  \let\midangle\pgfmathresult

  % slice
  \draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

  % outer label
  \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

  % inner label
  \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  \let\temp\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
  \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
  \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\foreach \p/\t in {20/type A, 4/type B, 11/type C,
                   49/type D, 16/other}
  {
    \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
    \addtocounter{b}{\p}
    \slice{\thea/100*360}
          {\theb/100*360}
          {\p\%}{\t}
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**How can I...**

1. Add custom colors to every single slice (e.g. `black!30`, `black!20`, etc.)?
2. Use decimal point numbers (23.32) instead of integers (23)?

---

### Example 2

There is [another nice example](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart-color/) with those beautiful antennas to the labels:

[image: Image of the pie chart]

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
% Pie chart with colors
% Author: Henri Menke
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      46.6/Chrome,
      24.6/Internet Explorer,
      20.4/Firefox,
      5.1/Safari,
      1.3/Opera,
      2.0/Other
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Maybe this one is more easy to adapt. How can I remove this ugly color cycle and replace it with custom colors (`black!20`, `black!30`, etc.) for every single slice?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go (I did it before I saw the second example you posted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\slice}[5]{
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  \let\midangle\pgfmathresult
  % \show\midangle
  % slice
  \draw[thick,fill=#5] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

  % outer label
  \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

  % inner label
  \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  \let\temp\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
  \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
  \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
}

\makeatletter
\let\stripatpt\strip@pt
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\newlength\lena
\newlength\lenb
\foreach \p/\t in {20.5/type A, 8.5/type B, 10/type C,
                   45.5/type D, 15.5/other}
  {
    \global\lena=\lenb
    \global\lenb=\dimexpr\lenb+\dimexpr\p pt\relax

    \edef\numbera{\stripatpt\lena}
    \edef\numberb{\stripatpt\lenb}

    \slice{\numbera/100*360}
          {\numberb/100*360}
          {\p\%}{\t}
          {black!\p}
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first version you posted used counters for the values of `a` and `b` (the percentage of the slice and the cumulative percentage), and TeX counters are integers, so (as I guess you tried and got an error) giving a non-integer would trigger an error.

So I replaced the counters by lengths (TeX equivalents of floating points) to allow any real number (I don't know about negative numbers, though).

Also I added a fifth argument to `\slice` that is the color. In the example I provided it is a mixture of black and the percentage of the slice. But you can add another item in the `\foreach` list with a specific color you may want.

### Edit:

Regarding your second example, it is simpler to adapt. First, you already have an explicit list of colors on the header of the file (`\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}`), just add at your taste. The only problem is that in the 29th line there is this:

```
\draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
```

so if you put a color like `black!10`, the `fill` option will be `\color!50`, which will expand to `black!10!50`, which does not exist and generates an error. Since you want to remove the colorful stuff, you can remove the `!50` from the line above, then the code will accept any color.

Other than that, you can remove this part and, as I said for the first example, add a third item in the `\forall` list, like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name/\color in {
      46.6/Chrome/black!10,
      24.6/Internet Explorer/black!20,
      20.4/Firefox/black!30,
      5.1/Safari/black!40,
      1.3/Opera/black!50,
      2.0/Other/black!60
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

then it should work like a charm `:)`.

[image]